# JavaFX add/remove button in TableView cell based on row value

Tags: javafx, tableview

This code has a TavbleView in it, the final column has buttons to act on the column, view & clear.  the clear button should only be present or enabled (either would be fine) if the given row is in a known state.  Here is the code to always display both buttons, it is coded right now that when the "canClear" property is false, no action is taken:

```
    private void addActionsToTable() {

        TableColumn<searchResults, Void> actionColumn = new TableColumn("Action");

        actionColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<searchResults, Void>() {
            private final HBox container;

            {
                Button viewBtn = new Button("View");
                Button clearBtn = new Button("Clear");

                viewBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        searchResults data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        gotoView(data.getLogNo());
                    }
                });

                clearBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        searchResults data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                        String logNo = data.getLogNo();
                        String serialNumber = data.getSerial();
                        
                        Boolean canClear = data.getCanClear();
                        if(canClear)
                        {
                            // Take action that has been cut for simplicity
                        }
                    }
                });

                container = new HBox(5, viewBtn, clearBtn);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(container);
                }
            }
        });

        SearchTable.getColumns().add(actionColumn);

        actionColumn.setPrefWidth(175);
    }
```

What need to happen so that the Clear button is either disabled or not displayed when data.getCanClear() is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `searchResults` (sic) class has a `BooleanProperty canClearProperty()` method:

```
    actionColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<searchResults, Void>() {
        private final HBox container;
        private final Button clearButton ;

        {
            Button viewBtn = new Button("View");
            clearBtn = new Button("Clear");

            viewBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    searchResults data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                    gotoView(data.getLogNo());
                }
            });

            clearBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    searchResults data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                    String logNo = data.getLogNo();
                    String serialNumber = data.getSerial();
                    
                    Boolean canClear = data.getCanClear();
                    if(canClear)
                    {
                        // Take action that has been cut for simplicity
                    }
                }
            });

            container = new HBox(5, viewBtn, clearBtn);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
            clearButton.disableProperty().unbind();
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                clearButton.disableProperty().bind(
                    getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex())
                        .canClearProperty().not());
                setGraphic(container);
            }
        }
    });
```